# How to limit voltage charge of supercapacitor

Tags: charger, supercapacitor, balancing

For a DIY project, I plan to charge an 100F 2.7V Supercapacitor using a 3.7V Lithium-ion 18650 battery. However, I need it to charge only until 2.25V.

Is there a simple circuit that I can build to limit the voltage\charge?

I basically need the stored energy to be ~250J.

Comment: "Are there any adjustable boards that I can buy" makes it a shopping question - not allowed

Comment: Buck converter + series resistor should do it.

Comment: How much current you can afford to be taken from your 3.7V battery?

Comment: @user287001 I'd only need to charge and discharge about 10-15 times per session, so I should have enough.

Comment: The max allowed current is needed for "how long the charging will take" If you can afford say 100 mA, then the full charging takes 38 minutes. 1A => 3 min 48 s, etc...

Comment: How much power dissipation can you afford?  ( heatsink on transistor etc )  What tolerance on V and 500J can you afford given C has a large tolerance? Never design something without including all the specs.

Comment: Basically, I was going to build an extremely basic and simple Capacitive Discharge Spot Welder, similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FZVzVo8gLM.

The battery would charge up the capacitor and I'd have the charge adjusted to the required power to make reasonably good welds.

So, I guess a 1-2A draw is good enough for me.

Comment: OK I'll design one that charges ... up in 2 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a power PNP Darlington or can make one with a power transistor and driver then get 2 Ultrabright RED LEDs and any old NPN signal transistors. These make good low voltage zener references.

Current sensing is on 330m should be 2 to 3 W.  The Upper LED turns on DIM when PNP Darlington is ON and then when output LED turns on DIM it switches off the series regulator and with 2A it takes <120 s.

[image]

[Java Sim design](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.05%200.6520819120330112%2050%205%2043%0Ar%20256%2080%20304%2080%200%200.33%0As%20128%2080%20160%2080%200%200%20false%0Ac%2064%2080%2064%20256%200%20100%200%0Av%20352%20256%20352%2080%200%200%2040%203.6%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20208%20176%20208%20128%200%20470%0A400%20208%20112%20208%2080%200%200_-1_0.3565750880764993_-0.46029997251264243_100%200_-1_0.8168750605891417_-0.5756779854361711_100%20-1%0A162%20304%20112%20208%20112%201%202.5%201%200%200%200.003%0Aw%20304%20112%20304%2080%200%0Aw%20256%2080%20224%2080%201%0Aw%20160%2080%20192%2080%200%0Aw%20176%20256%20208%20256%200%0Aw%20352%2080%20304%2080%202%0Aw%20176%20256%20128%20256%200%0Aw%20352%20256%20208%20256%200%0Aw%20208%20128%20208%20112%202%0Aw%20176%20256%20176%20224%200%0Aw%20208%20256%20208%20208%200%0Aw%2064%2080%20128%2080%202%0At%20176%20192%20208%20192%200%201%20-2.2169026722625618%200%20100%0At%20128%20208%20176%20208%200%201%200.24131797002832545%200%20100%0Ar%20304%20112%20304%20160%200%202000%0A162%20128%20112%20128%20208%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.001%0Ar%20128%20208%20128%20256%200%201000%0Aw%20128%20256%2064%20256%200%0Aw%20128%20112%20128%2080%200%0Aw%20304%20192%20304%20160%200%0Aw%20304%20192%20176%20192%202%0Ax%2031%2019%20230%2022%200%2024%20250J%20cap%20charger%0Ax%2033%2044%20393%2047%200%2024%20with%20current%20limit%20and%202.2V%20max.%0Ax%20329%2010%20406%2013%200%208%20T.%20Stewart%20Feb%202017%0Ao%203%2064%201%204355%205%201.6%200%201%2010%20Battery%0Ao%202%2064%200%204354%202.5%200.1%201%202%202%203%20Cap%20V%0Ao%202%2064%200%204353%205%203.2%201%202%202%203%20Cap%20I%0A)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very basic circuit that would limit the cap voltage to 2.7V.
The zener diode is used so that the 2.7V reference is fairly constant regardless of the battery voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXXk5p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you use an op-amp as shown, the charging rate will decrease as the cap approaches the reference voltage. If you were to replace the op-amp with a comparator, this shouldn't be an issue. To use a comparator, I believe a pullup resistor would need to be connected from the comparator output to the positive end of the battery.

Here is a [simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%203.3115451958692312%2050%205%2043%0At%20128%20128%20128%2096%201%20-1%202.877974875782884%201.3500000379005752%20100%0Aw%2064%2096%200%2096%200%0Aw%20240%20272%2064%20272%200%0A172%200%20192%20-48%20192%200%206%203.65%205%200%200%200.5%20Voltage%0As%200%20176%200%20128%200%200%20false%0Ag%200%20272%200%20288%200%0Ar%20208%2096%20144%2096%200%2010%0Aw%200%20192%200%20176%200%0Aw%200%20128%200%2096%200%0Ar%20128%20128%20128%20176%200%20100%0Ac%20240%20272%20240%20192%200%200.001%20-2.122025162116691%0A368%20240%20192%20304%20192%200%200%0A370%20240%2096%20240%20192%201%200%0Az%2064%20272%2064%20224%201%200.805904783%202.2%0Aw%2064%20272%200%20272%200%0Aa%20192%20176%20128%20176%201%205%200%201000000%202.121596106349174%202.122025162116691%0Aw%20192%20160%20208%20160%200%0Aw%20208%2096%20208%20160%200%0Aw%20208%2096%20240%2096%200%0Aw%20192%20192%20208%20192%200%0Aw%20208%20192%20208%20224%200%0Aw%20208%20224%2064%20224%200%0Ar%2064%20224%2064%2096%200%201000%0Aw%2064%2096%20112%2096%200%0Ao%204%2064%200%204103%200.0000762939453125%200.4%200%202%204%203%0Ao%2012%2064%200%204103%202.5%200.4%200%202%2012%203%0Ao%2011%2064%200%204103%202.5%203.2%200%202%2011%203%0A) that uses an *op-amp*.

Comment: Just use a Z-Diode and a resistor as voltage reference. With this modification the charging voltage is stable and does not depend on the input voltage. And add a series resistor after Q1 to limit charging current.

Comment: @auoa You beat me be 2 seconds!

Comment: haha, now you've to add the resistor, too :D

Comment: Are you sure that's how this circuit works--  To me, it looks like the cap will see voltages all the way up to a \$V_{CE}\$ drop of the battery when the comparator is off.

Comment: Have you actually simulated it?  I think you want an op amp in negative feedback, the 2.7 volts at the positive input and not a comparator. That would cap the voltage of the cap at 2.7V.  Note also that 2.25V was specced in the question.

Comment: Adding that resistor does lower the voltage, but it makes the approach kind of moot, doesn't it?

Comment: @ScottSeidman I had simulated what I thought was this circuit some time ago, however I don't have that particular software anymore and thus I don't have a way to simulate a comparator at this time. Looking at it now, I think it would at least require a pull-up resistor to work properly when the output goes to high-impedance....However, I was able to replace the comparator with an op-amp and it worked without further changes. Is that usable solution?

Comment: @ScottSeidman - Also I have gone over this circuit in my head a few times. If I'm using a comparator like the LM2903, and the (+) terminal is lower than (-), the output will be low, turning on the PNP. If the (+) terminal reaches (-), then the output would go to high impedance. Assuming a pullup resistor is on the base, the PNP should then turn off. Am I incorrect?

Comment: The op-amp solution would work even better if you put the 2.7V on the non-inverting input, and then used a negative feedback arrangement.  This would be a high- current voltage regulator, which is exactly what you're trying for.  In fact, it's the "example" schematic used in the Horowitz and Hill Appendices.  My issue with the comparator is the voltage at the collector, and how you regulate it, and what the battery is exposed to during switching times.  Try running your simulation in Circuitlab.  I just did (I had to rename the zener), and the voltage at the cap is 3.6V.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - I'm afraid I don't understand how I would use negative feedback, because the transistor is PNP. Thus the base must go low to turn it on. Also my trial for CircuitLab has expired and it is no longer letting me use the simulator. Here is a link to the java simulation using negative feedback and a PNP, you can swap it for an NPN by holding shift and dragging them: http://tinyurl.com/j5mko5o ...Does changing it to NPN and negative feedback help the issue? I am interested in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be a synchronous buck switching constant current source, with a voltage-limited output. If you don't find a pre-made one, you can use a switching LED driver and a comparator to stop it when target voltage is reached.

Comment: this would be most efficient sol'n